# Capybara 2.1 and Heroku config issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, capybara

Trying to do a `git push heroku` as a part of the [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=4.0#top) They're using `Capybara 2.1` 
which it would appear is causing an issue during the push. I get the following message:

```
IMPORTANT! Some of the defaults have changed in `Capybara 2.1`. If you're experiencing failures,
please revert to the old behavior by setting:

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.match = :one
  config.exact_options = true
  config.ignore_hidden_elements = true
  config.visible_text_only = true
end
```

[The documentation](http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1) merely says to "set these options" followed by the code above. I'm a novice, so I have no idea WHERE to set those options. My best guess would be in one of the many files in config, but not sure which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this doc (not certain which version of calybara this is for) it states to put the configuration file in lib/capybara.rb rather than an initializer.

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara.configure